# Qt (QOpenGLShaderProgram) - setting a uniform boolean value?

Tags: python, qt, opengl

How could I pass a boolean value to my fragment shader, using QOpenGLShaderProgram? (Python)

If my program is called `_program`, could i just use something like this:

```
self._program.setUniformValue('myVar', 1)
```

In order to pass a value of `true`, and then use it in my fragment shader using:

```
uniform bool myVar;
```

Would that be okay? Or should i do that using another way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ok. [`glUniform` documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glUniform.xhtml) says:

> Either the i, ui or f variants may be used to provide values for uniform variables of type bool, bvec2, bvec3, bvec4, or arrays of these. The uniform variable will be set to false if the input value is 0 or 0.0f, and it will be set to true otherwise.